# Using number pad keys with ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm programming a roguelike using the ncurses library for C++ and would like to have the character be controllable via the number pad. Currently I'm using the following approach:

```
case KEY_LEFT: 
    //Code for left movement
case KEY_RIGHT:
    //Code for right movement
...
//Numpad diagonals
case KEY_A1:
    //Code for moving up and to the left
case KEY_A3:
    //Code for moving up and to the right
...
```

The `KEY_A1`, `KEY_A3`, `KEY_C1`, and `KEY_C3` macros work for diagonal movement, but macros like `KEY_A2` don't exist for orthogonal movement. Whether or not numlock is on, the code for arrow keys doesn't work in this situation either.

How do I get input for the 2, 4, 6, and 8 keys on the number pad using ncurses? Alternatively, am I going about this incorrectly, and what would be a better approach?

Comment: Print the key value with printw("%o\n",key); then compare it with the key values in ncurses.h (usually in /usr/include) to see which key is being returned.  My keypad gives KEY_UP etc for the even keys

Comment: It depends upon the terminal (e.g., emulator).  It works with xterm.  Some so-called `TERM=xterm-256color` "terminal" programs don't implement the feature.

Answer (score -2):

By calling:

`addch(inputChar);`

I was able to ascertain that all the "standard" typing characters are just their ASCII equivalent, i.e.:

`'0'`, `'1'`, `'!'`, `'@'`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `'A'`, `'B'`, etc...

The same goes for Numpad **when** Num Lock is on. Alternatively, or for when Num Lock is off, you can call:

```cpp
addstr((std::to_string((int)inputChar) + " ").c_str());
```

which will yield an ASCII # that you could `#define` or the like.